# How to use window function to aggregate data based on date or rank column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

So I have a list of shipments and I have the the order total and the total for each individual shipment, but I'm struggling to come up with the code to create an additional column for cumulative shipments, which would include the current shipment, plus all previous shipments for that order.  Here's a result of what I have so far:

| OrderNo | ShipDate | OrderTotal | Shipment Total | Cumulative Shipments | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22396 | 2022-04-04 | 639,964 | 2,983 | 639,966 | 3 |
| 22396 | 2022-03-31 | 639,964 | 5,626 | 639,966 | 2 |
| 22396 | 2022-02-24 | 639,964 | 631,355 | 639,966 | 1 |

So these are 3 separate shipments for the same order.  The 1st shipments in row 3 is correct, but I need the cumulative shipments column for row 2 to be the shipments total sum of both, so $631,555 + 5,626.  Following that same logic, row 1 should be the sum of all 3, which at that point would be equal to the order total of $639,964.  Here's what that would look like:

| OrderNo | ShipDate | OrderTotal | Shipment Total | Cumulative Shipments | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22396 | 2022-04-04 | 639,964 | 2,983 | 639,964 | 3 |
| 22396 | 2022-03-31 | 639,964 | 5,626 | 636,981 | 2 |
| 22396 | 2022-02-24 | 639,964 | 631,355 | 631,355 | 1 |

I'm assuming the best way to accomplish this is using over(partition by ()), but I'm struggling to come up with the code.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    OrderNo,
    ShipDate,
    OrderTotal,
    [Shipment Total],
    SUM([Shipment Total]) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNo) AS [Cumulative Shipments],
    [Rank]
FROM Shipments
WHERE OrderNo = '22396'
```

The [Rank] column is from an earlier CTE which calculates the rank of that shipment based on shipdate:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.OrderNo ORDER BY d.ShipDate) AS [Rank]
```

I need something like SUM([Shipment Total]) where rank is equal or less than the current rank.  Same thing can be accomplished with the date column I'm sure, but just not sure how to finish the query

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please show your desired results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be half way there just missing an ordering criteria for a functioning cumulative sum, such as

```
select *, 
  Sum(ShipmentTotal) 
    over(partition by OrderNo 
         order by ShipDate rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from Shipments;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't bother building the CTE, but assuming you have some PK, you can self-join:

```
SELECT s.ShipmentsID, SUM(cumulative.ShipmentTotal) AS Sum
FROM Shipments s
LEFT JOIN Shipments cumulative ON cumulative.ShipDate <= s.ShipDate
GROUP BY s.ShipmentsID
```

| ShipmentsID | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 631355.52 |
| 2 | 636982.29 |
| 3 | 639966.04 |